# Wrong colours after exporting to MP4 using H.264 Codec

Tags: after-effects, h.264, color-grading, export

in my current project I am working in an sRGB colour space (32bpc) with the option "linearize workflow" enabled.
My composition looks fine in after effects, but after exporting to mp4 using H.264 Codec, the colours don't look the same, especially the very lights one.

[image]

the image above shows the difference. On the left hand side you see the colours after export and on the right hand side is how the colours look in after effects.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Sounds like either AE did not gamma transform the output or flagged the output incorrectly.

Comment: @Mulvya My workarround for now was to export as a Quicktime Movie (also using H.264) and than convert it to mp4.